# Xamarin Forms Quantity Toggle

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, shopping-cart

I had a look online but can't seem to find any solution at the moment.

I'm trying to simply update the total price when I toggle the quantity of a product.

For example.

Product price is : $50
Quantity is 2
Therefore total price would be $100

Here's my XAML code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
     <Stepper x:Name="stepper" ValueChanged="Handle_StepperValueChanged"/>
     <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference stepper}, Path=Value}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</StackLayout>

<ScrollView BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <Label x:Name="labelTotal" Text="{Binding ShoppingCartItemTotals}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="110" />
</ScrollView>
```

Here's my C# code:

```
ObservableCollection<FBProduct> fbproducts = new ObservableCollection<FBProduct>();
shoppingcartlistview.ItemsSource = fbproducts;

var producttitle = "Apple";
var productprice = "37.95";
var productimage = "Image goes here";

fbproducts.Add(new FBProduct
{
    ProductName = producttitle,
    ProductPrice = productprice,
    ProductImage = productimage
}); 

Console.WriteLine("Total Items:");

string ShoppingCartItemTotals = fbproducts.Select(a => new { Converted = Convert.ToDouble(a.ProductPrice.Replace("$", "")) }).ToList().Sum(a => a.Converted).ToString("#,0.00");

labelTotal.Text = "Total: " + ShoppingCartItemTotals;
```

Comment: first, why are you using a string for price and not a numeric type?  Second, I don't see anything in your code that represents Quantity

Comment: You should update the labelTotal in the `Handle_StepperValueChanged` method.

Comment: Thanks Jack, how would I get the value of the stepper and multiply by the rows product price? For example if the row's product price is $10 an the stepper qty value is 2 then how would I get qty * $10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Handle_StepperValueChanged` method, you can get the qty and price by following codes:

```
private void stepper_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //get qty
    double qty = e.NewValue;

    Stepper currentStepper = sender as Stepper;

    FBProduct currentProduct = currentStepper.BindingContext as FBProduct;

    //get price
    double price = Convert.ToDouble(currentProduct.ProductPrice);

    testP.ShoppingCartItemTotals = (qty * price).ToString();

}
```

I wrote a [basic demo](https://github.com/XfHua/basic-binding) with your code and you can check it out. Please feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Thank you so much Jack! It's working!! You the man! Is there a way to have multiple steppers for each product? For example each product row will have a stepper and if you change the qty for each of them, it will add up all the totals for what you've set?